# How do I update a subset of one SQLite table from the entire contents of another?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite table that must remain unchanged until a specific point. Any pending changes to records are stored in a second table, with identical fields. What I want to do, in pseudocode, is:

```
for each record U in secondTable
    find record R in firstTable, where R.uid = U.uid
    replace all fields in record R with those in record U
```

Is there some way to phrase an UPDATE command to do this in one fell swoop? If it helps, you can call the fields in both tables `uid`, `w`, `x`, `y` and `z`, with `uid` being the unique primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT OR REPLACE into firstTable (uid, w, x, y, z) 
  SELECT uid, w, x, y, z FROM secondTable
```

will work if `uid` is the primary key as you say.

The `REPLACE` conflict resolution is documented [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'll be testing it tonight. Slight modification though... the parentheses between the `SELECT` and the `FROM` give SQLite a fit. Removing them lets the statement compile, and presumably work.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
UPDATE R 
   SET R.w = U.w, 
       R.x = U.x, 
       R.y = U.y, 
       R.z = U.z 
 WHERE R.uid = U.uid;
```

...should work.

Comment: You forgot about declaring `U`